# How to map column values across 2 different data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I had first data frames as:

```
df1.head()

cust_id   state     pd

a1       NY         0.60
a2       Cal        0.26
a3       Florida    0.94
a4       NY         0.44
a5       Florida    0.65
a6       Cal        0.88

df2.head()

state     #cases  prop

NY         12      0.22
Cal        22      0.23
NY         44      0.33
Cal        55      0.11
Florida    44      0.65
Florida   121      0.52
```

How can i map these two data frames so that i have `#cases` and `prop` columns appended correctly to df1.

Comment: Can you specify more? Is this a simple merge?

Comment: yes..easy to do it in SQL...wanted to have this using pandas,,map function